# Filtrar resultados de una búsqueda en un DataTable a los que sean idéntios

Tags: datatables

Tengo una tabla con nombres de personas, por ejemplo:

```
Nombre
-------
Juan
Juan Antonio
Juana
```

Cuando quiero buscar por **Juan** en el campo de búsqueda, DataTable me muestra los tres, porque hace una búsqueda a aquellos campos que CONTENGAN la palabra buscada.

Quiero saber de qué forma puedo configurar el DataTable para que me devuelva los resultados **iguales** a la palabra indicada.

---

Ejemplo de lo que no quiero:

Tengo **(Juan, Juan Antonio, Juana, Juanete, Juanito)** y busco **(Juan)** y me devuelve **(Juan, Juan Antonio, Juana, Juanete, Juanito)**.

---

Lo que yo quiero:

Tengo **(Juan, Juan Antonio, Juana, Juanete, Juanito)** y busco **(Juan)** y me devuelve **(Juan)**.

Tengo **(Juan, Juan Antonio, Juana, Juanete, Juanito)** y busco **(Ju)** y me devuelve **()**. porque no existe ningún nombre Ju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

de acuerdo a lo que he leído, puedes crear un filtro personalizado para ello, desconozco si datable cuenta con algún parámetro de configuración para este aspecto. te adjunto este código, que tal vez te pueda servir.

Lo primero es definir la variable que contiene la tabla:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable()
```

Y con la siguiente función podrías hacer el filtro de coincidencia exacta. El identificador empleado corresponde al input donde digitas el valor a buscar.

```
$('.dataTables_filter input').unbind().bind('keyup', function() {
   var searchTerm = this.value.toLowerCase()
   if (!searchTerm) {
      table.draw()
      return
   }
   $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
      for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
         if (data[i].toLowerCase() == searchTerm) return true
      }
      return false
   })
   table.draw();   
   $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop()
})
```

Te paso la fuente en donde podrás tener mas claridad de la función en cuestión y hay un ejemplo de aplicación.

Fuente: https://code-examples.net/es/q/219389e